# Can Alfresco replace place holders with environment values?

Tags: environment-variables, alfresco

I am not an Alfresco user, so please excuse me if I use the wrong terminology. I have tried searching for this, but could not find the answer - as maybe it is not possible.

I have an static HTML page which I need to deploy to a a dev, staging and production server. The page contains a link, and this link should point to a different URL depending on the environment the HTML page is deployed to.

e.g. **test.html** looks like this, and I add/commit/upload this to Alfresco.

```
<html>
....
    <a href="{{LOGIN-URL}}">Log In</a>
....
</html>
```

And I then have **properties** such as this:

```
dev.LOGIN-URL=http://dev.example.com
stg.LOGIN-URL=http://stg.example.com
prod.LOGIN-URL=http://www.example.com
```

Is it possible for Alfresco to replace the placeholder with the correct value for that environment when the document is published?

Or can this be done another way?

Answer (score 1):

Nice question - You can define your stage by passing in a property via jvm args (http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/bean-override.html):

`-Dstage=dev` or `-Dstage=prod`

in your properties:

```
dev.LOGIN-URL=http://dev.example.com
stg.LOGIN-URL=http://stg.example.com
prod.LOGIN-URL=http://www.example.com
```

In your template:

```
<html>
    ....
        <a href="{{STAGE}}.{{LOGIN-URL}}">Log In</a>
    ....
</html>
```

Comment: My understanding (which could be wrong!) is that I upload **test.html** to one instance of Alfresco, and from there I publish/push it out various destination servers. So passing a JVM property via `-D` to Alfresco does not seem sufficient as it is a runtime decision depending on the destination I am publishing to.

Comment: then I didn't understand your requirement. How do you push/publish your test.html to various servers? via transferService?

Comment: I thought that a single Alfresco server could be setup to publish a file/asset to different destination servers, but maybe that is not the case, and a single Alfresco server can only publish to a single destination. Thanks for your help.